# Win32 TreeView AfterSelection

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

quick question...

I am working with treeview in win32 (VC++).

I want to remove selection facility provided for treeview. Can anyone tell what window message is posted onAfterSelect Event of tree view.

TV also has checkboxes. So disabling mouse click isn't an option...

Thanks in advance...

-
Varun

*More Info*
I am stuck at another point. My win32 application is essentially a modeless dialog - using CreateDialog & ShowWindow. After getting TVN_SELCHANGING, when I am returning 1, it isn't working. I think the default wndproc is getting called before I bypass the windows message. What should I do now?

Comment: Clearly you'll need *BeforeSelect* to prevent selection, AfterSelect would be too late.  TVN_SELCHANGING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem and just reversed the selection once it had already taken place.  If you're not responding to it, anyway, then there shouldn't be any side effects.

```
case WM_NOTIFY:     
    {
        if(wParam == IDC_TREE_MC)
        {
            LPNMHDR lpnmh = (LPNMHDR) lParam;
            TVHITTESTINFO ht = {0};

            if ((lpnmh->code  == NM_CLICK) && (lpnmh->idFrom == IDC_TREE_MC)) // For Treeview Check Box Check Event
            {
                DWORD dwpos = GetMessagePos();

                ht.pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(dwpos);
                ht.pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(dwpos);
                MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, lpnmh->hwndFrom, &ht.pt, 1);

                TreeView_HitTest(lpnmh->hwndFrom, &ht);

                if(TVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON & ht.flags)
                    PostMessage(hDlg, UM_CHECKSTATECHANGE, (WPARAM)lpnmh->hwndFrom, (LPARAM)ht.hItem);
                else
                    TreeView_SelectItem(lpnmh->hwndFrom, NULL);
            }
            else if ((lpnmh->code  == TVN_SELCHANGED ) && (lpnmh->idFrom == IDC_TREE_MC))
                TreeView_SelectNode(lpnmh->hwndFrom, NULL);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> to remove selection facility provided for treeview

Could you please clarify this?

Do you want to prevent user from changing selection?

If you really want to do it, insert WM_NOTIFY case handler in the parent window, check for NMTREEVIEW code member (lParam is a pointer to NMTREEVIEW).

If code is TVN_SELCHANGING return 1 if you want to prevent selection change.
Returning 0 will alow selection change.

Comment: Yes, I don't want selection on any node of my TreeView. After getting TVN_SELCHANGING, when I am returning 1, it isn't working. I think the default wndproc is getting called before I bypass the windows message. What should I do now?

Comment: I am not sure how do you handle WM_NOTIFY in your window procedure.
I always test my solutions and it works fine in my application. Could you post the code snippet of your window proc?

Comment: I have posted the snippet... For "What exactly is not working", Selection is still there if I am returning 1...

Answer (score 0):

> 

int CALLBACK WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    hWndDialog = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), NULL, WndProc);

```
if (hWndDialog != NULL)
{
    ShowWindow(hWndDialog, SW_SHOW);
}

while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if(!IsDialogMessage(hWndDialog, &Msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

INT_PTR CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDC_BTN_REFRESH:
        RefreshButtonHandler();             
        break;
    case IDC_BTN_ADD_INSTALL:
        AddInstallBtnHandler();
        break;
    case IDOK:
    case IDCANCEL:
        DestroyWindow(hDlg);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        break;  
    }
case WM_NOTIFY:     
    {
        if(wParam == IDC_TREE_MC)
        {
            LPNMHDR lpnmh = (LPNMHDR) lParam;
            TVHITTESTINFO ht = {0};

            if ((lpnmh->code  == NM_CLICK) && (lpnmh->idFrom == IDC_TREE_MC)) // For Treeview Check Box Check Event
            {
                DWORD dwpos = GetMessagePos();

                ht.pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(dwpos);
                ht.pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(dwpos);
                MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, lpnmh->hwndFrom, &ht.pt, 1);

                TreeView_HitTest(lpnmh->hwndFrom, &ht);

                if(TVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON & ht.flags)
                    PostMessage(hDlg, UM_CHECKSTATECHANGE, (WPARAM)lpnmh->hwndFrom, (LPARAM)ht.hItem);
                else
                    TreeView_SelectItem(lpnmh->hwndFrom, NULL);
            }
            else if ((lpnmh->code  == TVN_SELCHANGING ) && (lpnmh->idFrom == IDC_TREE_MC))
                return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
case UM_CHECKSTATECHANGE:
    {
        //Handle TreeView Check State Event
    }
    break;
}
return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
```

}

Sorry for the bad formatting... I am sleep deprived :-)